# How do I mock method calls in the following case?

Tags: python, mocking

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class A
   def __init__(self)
       self.bucket = S3Connection().get_bucket()

   def method(self)
       key = self.bucket.new_key()
       key.set_contents()
```

How do I test `method` my mocking calls to `new_key` and `set_content`? I started the following way

```
    @patch('my_file.S3Connection')
    test_method()
         a = A()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruno's Answer is a good tip but from your comment is clear that you are playing with a legacy code.

I'm not a `boto` expert but I guess is better if you patch the entire `S3Connection` instead just its `get_bucket()` method.

Now you must patch `S3Connection` *factory* (the constructor), after that `return_value` of your mock will be the object where we ask `get_bucket()`.

Your test become:

```
@patch('my_file.S3Connection')
test_method(mock_s3connection)
     mock_bucket = mock_s3connection.return_value.get_bucket
     a = A()
     #Just for fun ... check if the patch works like expected
     assert a.bucket is mock_bucket
     a.method()
     #check method logic
     assert mock_bucket.new_key.set_contents.called
```

Answer (score 0):

Some might say that the best way is to avoid hardcoding `S3Connection` in your class and pass it as an argument instead ie:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.bucket = connection.get_buckets()
```

or if you prefer to pass the connection class (or any callable) instead:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, connector):
        self.bucket = connector().get_buckets()
```

and then you can set `S3Connection` as a default:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, connector=S3Connector):
        self.bucket = connector().get_buckets()
```

Now you are free to pass any "Connection" class (or callable), which makes mocking easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't have an option to change the code